# Is there a java caching library to preload the results of slow running functions?

Tags: library, java

Say I have some function:

```
public Foo slowGetFoo(String id){
     //This process may take a long time
}
```

In order improve overall application responsiveness, I'd like to preload the results of this query, for a given list of ids, and store them in some collection, ready for immediate retrieval later.

eg. Let's say a `Foo` is a person, and we know that if a user is looking at a person, then they're also likely to look at their friends, so we want preload all friends.

```
public Foo getFoo(String id){


    Foo f = cache.retrieve(id);    //First attempt to retrieve it from the cache
    if (f == null) {
        f = service.slowGetFoo(id);      //if it's not there, then retrieve slowly 
    }

    cache.populate(f.getFriends());   //preload f's friends 

    return f; 
}
```

I started writing my own server side cache ([see here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121631/an-asynchronous-service-to-produce-a-results-cache-for-a-list-of-items)) but it feels like I'm reinventing the wheel, and I'm wondering if there's already a library that does this.

Comment: Do you need it to be distributed (among several servers)?

Comment: Also, should it be persistent (survive restarts of the program)? And will ever results get invalid?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - No doesn't need to be distributed or persistant, though ideally with contain an expiry timeout mechanism, or a way to prevent it from hoggging too many resources. Re: invalid results, yes - ideally it should be able to recover/store exceptions, though this isn't essential.